# Issue in YAML file in Azure Build pipeline when building docker file and pushing to Docker Hub

Tags: docker, xaml, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, dockerhub

I can't find the issue in YAML azure-pipeline file when I it create the docker build file, then I want to pushing it to my private repository 'username/docker-images' on Docker Hub.
Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have the following solution folder structure:

```
/src/Project1/Project1.csproj
/src/Project2/Project2.csproj
/Dockerfile.PRJ1
/Dockerfile.PRJ2
/Solution1.sln
```

When I build it with the following command on local Windows machine it succeeds:

```
  C:\> docker build -t Project1 -f src/Project1/Dockerfile .
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build

COPY ./*.sln ./
COPY ./src/Project1/Project1.csproj ./src/Project1/
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet restore ./Project1/Project1.csproj
COPY . /
RUN dotnet build ./Project1/Project1.csproj -c release --no-restore

#FROM build AS test
#RUN dotnet test

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish ./Project1/Project1.csproj -c release --no-build -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-alpine AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish ./

RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project1.dll"]]
EXPOSE 443
```

YAML Build and release pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
 
stages:
- stage: VSBuild 
  displayName: Build and Release to private DockerHub
  jobs:
    - job: VSBuild
      displayName: Build software
      pool:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'restore'
          projects: '**/*.csproj'
        displayName: 'Restore Nuget Packages'

      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'build'
          projects: '**/*.csproj'
          arguments: '--no-restore'
        displayName: 'Build projects'
        
      - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
        inputs:
          command: 'publish'
          publishWebProjects: false
          projects: '**/src/Project1/Project1.csproj'
          arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore'
          modifyOutputPath: false
        displayName: 'Publish'

      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: build
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: {GUID}
          repository: docker-images
          command: build
          Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile.PRJ1' #LINE UPDATED
          tags: idp-$(Build.BuildId)

      - task: Docker@2
        displayName: push
        inputs:
          containerRegistry: {GUID}
          repository: docker-images
          command: push
          tags: idp-$(Build.BuildId)
```

I get the following error in the Azure Pipeline:

```
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-alpine
 ---> 9e12b747545b
Step 2/29 : COPY ./*.sln ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified
##[error]COPY failed: no source files were specified
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Solution was: Move the /Project1/Dockerfile to .SLN level it will go further.
But now it comes with the following error, what should be standing at this step?

```
Step 11/29 : RUN dotnet test
 ---> Running in 86a9fa6e54d5
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet test' returned a non-zero code: 1
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet test' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

My solution was to removed the 2 lines from the Dockerfile:

```
FROM build AS test
RUN dotnet test
```

Comment: What about this issue, does the answer will help you? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According your yaml settings, we find your docker file is under the folder 'src/Project1'.
And based on the operating rules of docker file, the copied file must be in the same directory as the docker file.
So, we recommend you can move your docker file to the folder same with /Solution1.sln, and modify your yaml file.